# How to Query Accident Information in FHIR?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm investigating HL7-FHIR for use in a decision support context and was trying to find out how to extract accident information for a given patient.  I had assumed this would be a resource type but I can't find anything that fits.

Comment: What do you mean by "accident information"?

Comment: @Grahame: in the New Zealand context, that would be: Accident description, Date of accident, ACC claim number (ACC is the national accident insurer in NZ) and any number of diagnoses each of which would have a Read code, a description and a side (L,R,NA)

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a specific resource for this information. Mostly, this sounds like a series of observations, and perhaps a context linking them together. It's the context piece that we haven't yet got (our initial focus was on PHR). That will definitely be in the next version, but for now, I guess you just use the observations directly